# How to determine the size of a Point2f variable?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
parallel_for_(Range(0,npoints),LKTrackerInvoker(prevPyr[level*lvlstep1],deriveI,nextPyr[level*lvlstep2],prevPts,nextPts,status,err,winsize,criteria,level,maxlevel,flags(float)minEigThreshold);
```

Above is a function in OpenCV, which is used to calculate optical flow for previous pyramid images(const Mat& prevPyr) and next pyramid images(Mat& nextPyr).
Now I want to process nextPts(Point2f* nextPts), I need the size of nextPts.

I tried to look up OpenCV documentation but could not find any member function to get the size, Point2f cannot be converted to Mat, either. So, how can I get the size for a Point type variable and when should I use Point2f instead of Mat or InputArray, I'm not clear what the advantages of class Point are.

Any relevant reply would be appreciate a lot.

Comment: `sizeof` wouldn't work for you?

Comment: As far as I know, Point2f is a representation of a point in a 2d space - (x, y). I didn't understand your problem very well, but it makes no sense to me trying to convert a point to a matrix or to an array. They are representing different things...

Comment: sizeof takes effect on compile stage, while I get the variable nextPts  at runtime,  so that might not work.

Comment: The size of Point2f does not vary. As I said, it is a point in a 2d space. Basically, it is a couple of floats...

Comment: Point2f* var is not necessarily a single point, it could actually be the coordinates of a point set. In that case, isn't Mat or InputArray more powerful?

Comment: is nextPts a pointer of Point2f and you want to know how how many of them are stored (likean array) behind that pointer in memory? Probably it is npoints number of Point2f objects there.

Comment: yes, InputArray and Mat are more powerful, but openCV intially was a C library and not every old function got a review.

Comment: @Micka what if Point2f* nextPts change its size, i.e., delete some of points, in the function?

Comment: if you know the number of points in the beginning and add/delete yourself you can adjust the number yourself. Is your question abour how to use a specific openaCv fumction correctly? Then better give  link to that function's doc

Comment: The link to the function I'm using is: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323

Comment: It is a pyramidal optical flow implementataion. I want to get the nextPts for each iteration and each pyramid.@Micka

Comment: if you are using c++ (the tag suggests it), you could re-write your method and pass a vector, and handle it with iterators. It is not really safe to change the size of an array when looping through it...

Comment: as you can see in the doc, input and output types should be InputArray and OutputArray = std::vector<cv::Point2f>